# Python: concatenate string inside list

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I want to output a list like:

```
operation1 = [
    'command\s+[0-9]+',
]
```

Where the pattern `[0-9]+` is to be dynamically filled.

So I wrote:

```
reg = {
    'NUMBER' : '^[0-9]+$',
    }

operation1 = [
    'command\s+'+str(reg[NUMBER]),
]
print operation1
```

But i am getting an error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   6       
NameError: name 'NUMBER' is not defined
```

Help needed! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `reg['NUMBER']`, I guess. 'NUMBER' is not a variable

Answer (score 0):

`NUMBER` should be a string:

```
reg['NUMBER']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the key in quotes (Perl allows not adding quotes, but not Python):

```
operation1 = [
    'command\s+'+str(reg['NUMBER']),
]
```

You also don't need the call to `str`:

```
operation1 = [
    'command\s+'+reg['NUMBER'],
]
```

You could even do this (although not related to the original question):

```
operation1 = [
    'command\s+{}'.format(reg['NUMBER']),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using variable `NUMBER`, which is not defined. I think what you wanted to use is string `'NUMBER'`, like this:

```
>>> operation1 = ['command\s+[0-9]+',]
>>> reg = {'NUMBER' : '^[0-9]+$'}
>>> operation1 = [x + reg['NUMBER'] for x in operation1]
>>> operation1
['command\\s+[0-9]+^[0-9]+$']
```